# onpropertychange event vs keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm trying to mimic Google suggestions over here: [yous-design](http://yous-design.com/)

It works perfect in Chrome/Firefox etc. but not in IE. I googled for it and it turns out that IE doesn't support the oninput event which in the code looks like this:

```
el("inp").oninput=function(){
  addScript("http://www.google.nl/complete/search?callback=suggest&q="+this.value);
}
```

Instead I would have to use the onpropertychange event for IE. But when I replace the event it still doesn't work. I think this piece of code is counteracting:

```
$('#inp').keydown(
function (e){
    var curr = $('#test').find('.current'); etc.etc.etc.
```

I think the keydown(/keyup) is counteracting with the onpropertychange event. But what should I replace keydown/keyup with? Are there any other alternatives at all? Should I rewrite the code?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead of `onpropertychange`, use `onKeyUp` on IE.

`onpropertychange` is buggy in IE and doesn't fire for all keys (delete and backspace I think).

Comment: That doesn't work. I don't think you can use onkeyup twice in the same document. And furthermore I think in this particular case the onkeyup and the keydown(/keyup same effect) of the Jquery are counteracting so now the whole thing doesn't work at all in Chrome/Firefox/IE (please notice the plain javascript and Jquery)